# JavaScript Appended Element Text Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to create an online to do list for users and I want it to function so that when you enter a task and click the 'JotIT' button the task is appended.

So far the function to append works but the text is not visible for some reason even though when I inspect it, the text shows up in the HTML.

```
<script>
    var welcome = 'Welcome To JotIT';

    var jotItem = function()
        {
            //Create & Get the necessary elements
            var item = document.createElement('input'),
            space = document.createElement('br'),
            form = document.getElementById("listing"),
            frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            textVal = document.getElementById("input-jot");

            //Set Attributes to list item
            item.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
            item.setAttribute('name', 'jot-list');

            //If there is no input in the textbox then create an alert popup
            if(textVal.value === "")
                alert("Please insert a value");
            else {
                item.innerHTML = textVal.value;
                frag.appendChild(item);
                frag.appendChild(space);
                form.appendChild(frag);
                textVal.value = ""; 
            }
        }
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="head">JotIT</h1><br>
    <p> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(welcome);</script></p>
    <input type="form" id= "input-jot">
    <button class = 'btn-info' id="jot-down" onclick=jotItem();>JotIt!</button>
    <!-- TODO: Add form submit tag instead of ul tag -->
    <!-- TODO: Align the list items -->
    <form id = "listing" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" name="me"> Start </input>

    </form>

  </body>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your JavaScript to suggest that `frag` has any contents. When you use `item.innerHTML = textVal.value` do you mean `frag.innerHTML`?

Comment: I didn't know that frag itself had to have content. I just added content to the elements that I will append to frag. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to insert a label. Inputs should be self closing / empty elements. In particular an input of type checkbox won't correctly display a label. Use the label element for this purpose instead.

```js
    var welcome = 'Welcome To JotIT';

    var jotItem = function() {
      //Create & Get the necessary elements
      var item = document.createElement('input'),
        label = document.createElement('label'),
        space = document.createElement('br'),
        form = document.getElementById("listing"),
        frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        textVal = document.getElementById("input-jot");

      //Set Attributes to list item
      item.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
      item.setAttribute('name', 'jot-list');

      //If there is no input in the textbox then create an alert popup
      if (textVal.value === "")
        alert("Please insert a value");
      else {
        label.innerText = textVal.value;
        frag.appendChild(label);  // here goes the label
        frag.appendChild(item);
        frag.appendChild(space);
        form.appendChild(frag);
        textVal.value = "";
      }
    }
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="head">JotIT</h1>
  <br>

  <input type="form" id="input-jot">
  <button class='btn-info' id="jot-down" onclick=jotItem();>JotIt!</button>
  <!-- TODO: Add form submit tag instead of ul tag -->
  <!-- TODO: Align the list items -->
  <form id="listing" method="get">
    <label>Start</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="me" />

  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow silly me, I missed that. Thanks a lot. But now the issue is the text is appearing in front of the checkbox. How do I align it properly?

Comment: depends on what you expect... anyhow, this would probably be a new question.

Comment: If you want the label and checkbox to appear reversed, then append the `item` before the `label`. Think of appending to a stack.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the fact that you're adding the label to the input incorrectly. Use the below HTML syntax and it will resolve your issue:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="jot-list" />The Text</label>
```